# Access member of underlying type of sequence (Scala)

Tags: scala, collections

```
package p {
 trait A{ type B }
}

trait C {
  val D: Seq[p.A]

  def m(t: D. ...) = ???
}
```

I would like to refer to type `B` through `D`. How can I do this?

**Note**

The code that I inherited was:

```
package p {
 trait A{ type B }
}

trait C {
  val D: p.A

  def m(t: D.B) = ???
}
```

This makes sense in that context and certainly compiles.

Comment: There the dependency is invariant, so just use `p.A`, why through `D`? Look like an x/y question.

Comment: @cchantep sorry the goal is rather to access `B`. With regard to `why`, this is nearly inherited code so right now I'm guessing. I think D. ... is not equal to p.A.B so this prevents certain instantiations of the template, which in my particular case study can be useful.

Comment: Your code is confused. First `D` is a value, `val D:...`, then it's a type, `t: D...`. It helps if you post code that compiles (or comes reasonably close).

Comment: `def m(t: D. ...)` doesn't make much sense, since `D` is a value, and not a type

Comment: @jwvh I added the original code, which compiles, in a note. Hope it helps.

Comment: A `Seq()` of `A`s has no underling type `B`. Each element in the seq can implement a different `B` type.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to achieve. `t` is already of type `B`. What do you want to do with ir?

Comment: Your original code uses path dependent types, each value `A` might implement an different `a.B`. This is used correctly in the original code, not so in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses path-dependent types.

```
trait A { type B }
class A1 extends A { type B = String }
class A2 extends A { type B = Int }
```

In each of these types implementation uses different `type B`. So you cannot just refer to type `B` directly, only through a path from the value.

```
trait Foo {
  type Bar
  def operationA(bar: Bar) = X
  def operationB(bar: Bar) = Y
}
val foo1: Foo = ...
val foo2: Foo = ...
```

Here I cannot know of `foo1.Bar =:= foo2.Bar`. I don't know anything about it. I only know that I could pass `foo1.Bar` into `foo1.operationA` or `foo1.operationB` and pass `foo2.Bar` into `foo2.operationA` or `foo2.operationB`.

This is used correctly in the original code because you are fixing D to be a specific immutable value (`D`). So the types working on this value are referring to it (`D.B`).

`Seq` of `D` cannot be used that way. You would have to do something like

```
package p {
 trait A{ type B }
}

trait C {
  val Ds: Seq[p.A]

  def m(D: p.A)(t: D. ...) = ???
}
```

and then while working on `Ds` passing each value of if into `m` first, followed by a value derived from it (so that it would have this `D. ...` type) next.